# Cerrar consola CMD al terminar proceso con shell script

Tags: linux, bash

Como puedo cerrar una consola de cmd al terminar el proceso con un .sh hice una validacion pero no se como cerrar la consola al finalizar el processo cuando termine de ejecutatlo

Trate de correrlo dentro de la misma pero no pudo ser posible

ya que en mi scipt corro un start y esto me abre un cmd quiero que cuando termine el cmd lo cierro por completo pero desde mi script .sh

```
 start cqlsh -k fsainstqual -e "COPY instrumentmanufacturer (id,createdby,createdtime,description,lastmodifiedby,lastmodifiedtime,name) to '../Documents/instrumentmanufacturer.cql'"
```

Comment: Tal vez si capturas el `exit code` del último comando ejecutado (`$!`), y haces un `exit 0`. Creo deberías poner algo como: `if [$! -eq 0] then exit 0 fi` (respetando los saltos de linea respectivos). Prueba eso, y comentas. Saludos

Comment: Como podrias darme alguna idea?

Comment: Hola chicos ya pude resolver el problema pero como puedo determinar un path predeterminado ya que la ruta de nuestras carpetas es diferente

Comment: Me alegra que lo resolvieras. Lo de las rutas si que no lo entiendo. ¿Podrías aclarar que tratas de hacer? Puedes poner un ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: lo que pasa es que mi carpeta de db lo tengo en descargas y mi equipo lo tiene en otro lado no se si hay manera con linux de encontrar ese path pero si utilizo PATH esto es para linux necesito para windows